# Insertar un enlace javascript dentro de un script

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo un enlace a un html mediante javascript

```
<script>
    function abrir(url) {
        open(url,'','top=300,left=300,width=500,height=10,scrollbars=1,location=0,status=0,menubar=0') ;
    }
</script> 

<div class="misco"><a href="javascript:abrir(('textos/saquina.html'))">Texto saquina</a></div>
```

Ahora estoy añadiendo un código para cookies y tiene un apartado de configuración y me gustaría añadir el enlace de arriba href="javascript:abrir(('textos/saquina.html'))" que en html funciona pero aquí dentro de otro script no.

```
<script>

    window.CookieConsent.init({
        // More link URL on bar
        modalMainTextMoreLink: el enlace va aquí ¿cómo lo añado?
        // How lond to wait until bar comes up
        barTimeout: 1000,
        // Look and feel
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Si te he entendido bien, lo que quieres es poder utilizar dentro del <script> la misma URL de la nueva ventana que acabas de abrir, ¿es así?

Comment: La misma url pero con la función de abrir esa ventana. Quiero meter en ese script último el enlace de es html pero con la funcion abrir. Puesto de manera erronea porque no me funciona algo así.`código`  <script>

        window.CookieConsent.init({
// More link URL on bar
    modalMainTextMoreLink: href="javascript:abrir(('textos/saquina.html'))"
    // How lond to wait until bar comes up
    barTimeout: 1000,
    // Look and feel
    
        });
      </script>`código`

Answer (score 0):

Si tienes el primer  de una página, con una función `abrir('http://url-concreta/pagina)`, y lo que quieres es saber el valor de esa variable 'url', puedes saberlo con la función `window.location.href`, que te devolverá la URL actual en la que te encuentras (la nueva ventana que has abierto), y deberá coincidir con el valor del parámetro de la llamada `open`.

Si quieres tener más info sobre el location, aquí tienes un [enlace](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp).

Comment: Sé cuál es la url  l La manera fácil es poner directamente la url textos/saquina.htm pero no quiero que la abra así. Quiero que la abra mediante la función abrir del codigo que públique en la pregunta. Aquí seria así sin más  <script> modalMainTextMoreLink:  textos/saquina.html   </script> pero lo que quiero es esto  <script> modalMainTextMoreLink: javascript:abrir(('textos/saquina.html'))   </script>  abrirlo así con esta función y no funciona

Comment: Porque la manera que estás intentando implementarlo no es lógica. Los compañeros te están dando una solución más obvia y efectiva.

Comment: Como comenta @ortiz, creo que estás mezclando conceptos, y por eso es un poco más complicado entender lo que quieres hacer. Si pudieras poner ese "javascript:abrir", se interpretaría y se abriría automáticamente, y no creo que sea ese el objetivo de lo que quieres conseguir, ya que por el nombre de la propiedad que necesita el objeto del método `init` (en concreto: `modalMainTextMoreLink`) será una cadena lo que está esperando.